# How to identify third party hardware devices for credit cards and their APIs for Windows 8 Tablet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, windows-8

I am new to Windows 8 tablet.  My question is how to identify third party hardware devices for credit cards and their APIs that need to integrate into Windows 8 Tablet Type for Onsite Studio App?

Which type of languages support this API for Windows 8 tablets?

Answer (score 0):

By Windows 8 tablet, I presume you mean a metro/modern style application? If so you'll be limited using Windows 8 for this. Instead I would highly recommend looking at the API's provided in Windows 8.1. Using the newer APIs you have three options:

1) Windows.Devices.PointOfService - which is the port of POS.NET across to the WinRT namespace. This basic API's allow you to access POS peripherals such as MSR readers. Example code can be found on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182882.aspx#two

2) If you want to use NFC-based cards (tap and pay) - theoretically you can use the WinRT port of the Smartcard framework. This isn't as straightforward as the above, and requires some understanding of how smartcards work. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.smartcards.aspx

3) You can assess devices such as Square which use a 3.5mm audio jack. WinRT provides functionality to access audio devices, and you'll need to convert the incoming WAV data into bytes which represent the MSR information. Again not so straight forward but is a commonly requested approach.

All three of the above solutions are independent of language (C#/C++/JS), but hopefully the above APIs point you in the right direction.